# Rails how to validate that for each first member of a pair in table the second member is the same

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, model

I'm new to rails and if I have the following table:

```
     a | b | c
     ---------
     1 | 2 | 3
     1 | 3 | 4
```

I want to ensure that if I add a new entry with a b-value of 2, then it must have a c-value of 3 as well, the same applies to an entry with a b-value of 3 and a c-value of 4. Any ideas what's the easiest way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

You can always add [callbacks](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_callbacks.html) for that.

I am assuming that you have a model named `Member`

```
class Member < ApplicationRecord

before_save :update_next_field

private

def update_next_field
  case self.b
  when 2
    self.c = 3
  when 3
    self.c = 4
  end
end

end
```

Answer (score 0):

You could have a custom validation.

Assuming your class is `Member` like @rahul did in his answer.

```
class Member < ActiveRecord::Base
  validate :value_b_to_c_correspondence

  def value_b_to_c_correspondence  
    if (self.b == 2 && self.c != 3) || (self.b == 3 && self.c != 4)
      # add some error to the model. Any one of the below three should be enough or all of them depending on your need.
      errors.add(:b_to_c_correspondence, "Wrong values")
      errors.add(:b, "Wrong value for c")
      errors.add(:c, "Wrong value for b")
    end
  end
end
```